# How do I get the no of processes that have been created since the last boot on a Linux machine

Tags: linux, process

How do I get the no of processes that have been created since the last boot on a Linux machine.

I want to use it in a C++ program so I prefer just knowing which proc file has it

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/acct/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to know the number of `forks` there is `/proc/stat`:

> ```
> processes XXXX
> Number of forks since boot.
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at processes inside `/proc/stat` will show you the number of processes created which may include the processes created using `fork()` as well as `clone()`.
To get the number of procceses forked since bootup you will have to run

```
vmstat -f
```

Answer (score 1):

Fork count since last boot:

```
vmstat -f
```